# StringTemplate - How to iterate through list of business objects and output simple html?

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

I've just started using [StringTemplate](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+Documentation) in my C# project. I went through the documentation, but I can't seem to find a way to implement this simple scenario:

I have a list of simple business objects (let's say Orders) and I want them displayed inside a UL tag inside my html template.

So, my .st template looks like this (pseudo-code):

`<html> some text <ul>[Order template]<li>[Order name here]</li>[/Order template]</ul></html>`

and I want my output to be:

`<html> some text <ul><li>Order 1</li><li>Order 2</li>...</ul></html>`

I can't figure out how to make this work using StringTemplate. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a nice post that can help you: [Localizable text template engine using StringTemplate 4](http://netmvc.blogspot.com/2012/04/localizable-text-template-engine-using_23.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should use the following syntax:

```
<ul>
    $orders: {order|
        <li>Order $order.OrderId$</li>
    }$
</ul>
```

The documentation about this feature is really hard to find, I found some info [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/course/601/lectures/stringtemplate.html) (search for the pipe symbol |).

Answer (score 0):

That works for me also.  If you are calling StringTemplate from Antlr as a StringTemplateGroup, the syntax is a little different.  Replace $ with <>.

```
group DTO;

assign1(m, attributes) ::= <<
package demo;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class <m> implements Serializable {
    public <m>() {
        super();
    }

<attributes : {attribute |
protected <attribute.type> <attribute.name>;

public <attribute.type> get<attribute.name>() {
    return <attribute.name>;
}

public void set<attribute.name>(<attribute.type> <attribute.name>) {
    this.<attribute.name> = <attribute.name>;
}
}>
}

>>
```

Comment: How do I get it working if for eg: "attribute.type" returns a complex object of type "Type" class. I am trying to implement the same, where the "attribute.type" returns an Object "Type", which has an attribute "typeName". I am unable to retrieve the TypeName. Please help !!